# Qt C++ Read do while loop not initializing

Tags: c++, qt, file-io, qfile

I've checked if the location of the file was correct and it was so I have no idea why my program is not working. I have literally been looking at it for a few hours but I still cant find out whats wrong. I would really appreciate any input.

Text in text file: Bob Janurary 1 2000 Math 7A 5 41 7 9 8 8 9

relevant code:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString name, month,  subject, level;
    int day, year, apages, total, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten;

    QFile file("C:/Users/brandan/Desktop/GUIPrograms/Kumon.txt");

    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        QString line;

        do
        {
        qDebug() << "test";
        line = stream.readLine();
        qDebug() << line;
        } while(!line.isNull());
    }

}
```

Comment: What you mean by "not working"?

Comment: QDebug isn't outputting anything.

Comment: Also, why is your condition `if (!file.open(...))`? You're checking if the open failed, and then commencing to perform a read from the file. Instead just do `if (file.open(...))`.

Comment: Why are you using the !not operator?

Comment: Are you sure you compiled in debug mode?

Comment: Your `if` condition says "if the file does NOT open".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking if the file is opened correctly with

```
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
```

so your code is executed only if the file is NOT opened correctly. Use

```
if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
```